# How to remove item from state using key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to remove an item from state.

I have the `key` id (as `this.props.result._id`) which want to delete.

I will want to run this function as a result of the .then in the `fetch` (`trash` function).

How can this be achieved?

```
class Data extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { hits } = this.props
    this.components = []
    return (
      <div>
        {hits.map(hit => 
          <ItemResult ref={ref => this.components.push(ref)} 
          key={hit._id} result={hit} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ItemResult extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      item: props.result,
    };
  }
  deleteItem = event => {
    // console.log('This gives undefined', item)
    this.setState({
      item: []
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}> Delete </button>
          <h2> This appears {this.props.result.title}</h2>              
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete the `props` key. There are two way in your case:

1. call any callback from your parent component (where are you specifying this prop) and remove/modify it there
2. but it will be better if you palce this prop in a `state` of the component. Then you'll be able to work with it as you wish and don't relay to the props.

Answer (score 0):

Key is more of an internal react property. If I were you the way I'd probably go about this is to create a dynamic id on each of the elements, then address that specific id when trying to remove it.

```
class Data extends React.Component {
     render(){
const { hits } = this.props
this.components = []
return (
  <div>
    {hits.map(hit => 
      <ItemResult ref={ref => this.components.push(ref)} 
      key={hit._id} id="{'hitNum' + hit._id}" result={hit} />)}
  </div>
    )
  }
}

class ItemResult extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { result } = this.props
    return (
        <div key={result._id}>
          <h1>{result._source.title}</h1>
          <DeleteButon/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

class DeleteButon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  trash() {
    return fetch(DATA_API + this.props.result._id + '/', {
     method: 'PUT',
     body: JSON.stringify({deleted:true})})
      .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
          //.then remove the id={'hitNum' + hit._id} it belongs to in ItemResult 
  }
  render () {
    return (
     <button className="trash" onClick={this.trash} >
     Delete item # {this.props.result._id}
    </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you've just pasted my code. Could you please show how this is done using actual code?

Comment: I repasted your code with a slight addition! check out when you're creating the actual react elements, you're adding a unique id starting generically with hitNum and then concatenating on whatever the id is. This can then be accessed later on in the .then function to actually remove the specific element you want to remove.

Comment: Please give a full example showing the .then function to remove it- thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to solve the problem of changing your parent using `React` is to pass down a callback into your component.

So when defining the `DeleteButton` component, it might look like this:

```
<DeleteButton onDelete={() => console.log('handle delete')} />
```

**If you want to change Props though..**

Then you might want to trigger a re-render in the parent with different props being passed down. This is how React flourishes. A uni-directional flow of information. If the removal of an `ItemResult` changes some central state, then all props are derived from that central state, you can simply cause the components to re-render and it will have a new set of props, with the desired `ItemResult` missing.

**Read about..**

- Redux is the current, idiomatic way of solving this problem: https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/intro-to-react-redux-pros

Comment: Could you provide a callback to do this? I am not using nor familiar with redux

Comment: At risk of it costing me precious reputation, I'd rather you had a go at it first and I provided pointers. Redux is a little overboard is this is a small app, but it's very powerful if your app might scale; plus it's largely industry standard for React at the moment.

Comment: Sure, I've edited my answer given your advice using a .then call back but I didn't have success. Could you please review?

Comment: I've provided several edits- could you please assist? I still have not got it working

Comment: When you're passing in a function that uses the `this` keyword, you need to tell it which `this` to use. i.e `onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}`

Comment: Ok, I have done this, but it still does not find the item. Could you please provide a little more info?